# Javascript libary geojson maps every kind of projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, data-visualization, geojson

I need a JavaScript which is able to visualize GeoJson maps. I already tried d3.js and Leaflat but I have problem because in d3.js you have to define manually the projection and Leaflat only accepts EPSG: 4326.

I get the data from a database and there could be data with a different projection, so the visualization wouldn't work for that.

Is there a JavaScript library which can display GeoJson data with any projections without defining it manually? So the projection should be identified automatically and the data should be displayed right.

Comment: There's no way to do that -- GeoJSON doesn't carry enough information to reliably infer the projection.

Comment: Give an example how this should be useful in any case. It makes no sense to me sorry.

Comment: For instance if I get the data from a database and the data changes (other projection). The code doesn't work anymore for the new data so I have to edit the code everytime. If the data changes a lot (different projection) it would be great if the code works also for that kind of data.